# How can I stop a UIView movement in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm messing around with Swift for the first time and have a square on the screen.  The square starts by moving to the right.  When I tap on it I want it to go up.  I don't want it to continue to the right at all, I want it to just go straight up.  Unfortunately the physics and gravity make it curve to the right some more before it goes up.  What can I do to completely stop the gravity pull and acceleration of my object, before setting the gravity to the new value?

This turns the object in the right direction, but I need it to come to an instant stop before doing this.

```
if(self.gravity.gravityDirection.dx == 1){
 self.gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(-1.0, 0.0)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to stop an item being affected by a behavior is to remove the item from the behavior or remove the behavior from the animator. For example, here you might remove self from the existing gravity behavior.

Comment: I tried self.gravity.removeItem(self.squareView) and then at the end of my if statement added gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [self.squareView]), but all that did was cause my square to slow down and then come to a complete stop when it touched the edge of the screen.  No turn was made.

Comment: Those are just words. I have no idea what you're doing or whether it makes any sense. What I suggested, works fine. The moving view sharply turns the corner, as you requested.

Comment: I don't doubt that you've got it working, I'm just trying to figure out how to apply it to what I have.

Comment: Absolutely - if you've got more going on in your animator, that could affect it. But the point is that what I said definitely stops the moving view dead in its tracks, which is what you asked for. And the movie proves it. If that isn't happening, you need to figure out what else is going on.